# Pass string as parameter into XSLT in PHP

Tags: php, xml, string, xslt, xpath

I have a question about passing parameter from PHP code into xslt. 
Here is my php code:

```
$searchStr = 'article[@key = &apos;journals/acta/Saxena96&apos;]';
$xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltProcessor->registerPHPFunctions();
$xsltProcessor->importStyleSheet($this->xslDoc);
$xsltProcessor->setParameter('', 'search_condition', $searchStr);
```

Here is XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="dblp">
        <form> 
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th style="text-align:left">Auteur</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Titre</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Pages</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Volumne</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Journal</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Numéro</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">URL</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">EE</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Modification</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$search_condition">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="author/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="pages/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="volume/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="journal/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="number/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="url/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ee/text()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>  
        </form> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run it, I always have error message:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): runtime error: file
>   file:///D:/includes/xslt/article.xsl line 31 element for-each in
>   D:\includes\bean\articles.php on line 67
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): The 'select' expression does
>   not evaluate to a node set. in D:\includes\bean\articles.php on line
>   67

But when I input directly the string condition : 'article[@key = 'journals/acta/Saxena96']' into xslt, it's worked well.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I pass an XPath expression as an XSL param using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27774013/367456)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the parameter on `stylesheet` level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="search_condition">defaultValue</xsl:param>

...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You're trying to iterate the string as an XPath expression in the `for-each`.
This will not work. It will be treated as a string literal.

A possible solution is eXSLT [dyn:evaluate](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html).

Comment: Dear ThW, thanks for your response. Could you explain more clearly, how to install the eXSLT dyn:evaluate? I still have the problem of importStylesheet(): compilation error. Thanks very much.

Comment: @minh-hieu.pham: The PHP manual has more information: [`XSLTProcessor::hasExsltSupport`](https://php.net/xsltprocessor.hasexsltsupport) and the following usage report [How to use embedded EXSLT from XSLTProcessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1372810/367456) (it's not about the question - it asks wrong - but just for the example given there)